# For loop inside jQuery call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a JavaScript function on an ASP.NET Master Page that I can call from the Content Pages.  I would essentially pass the function a gridview Client ID and a number of columns, and I would use this function to call a jQuery `tablesorter` on the gridview, looping through the number of columns specified in the function call.

I would call the function like so:

`sortTable(<%=gridView1.ClientID%>, 8)`

I have written the function like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function sortTable(gridView, numberOfColumns) {
            $("#" + gridView).tablesorter({
                headers: {
                    for(var i = 0; i<numberOfColumns; i++){
                        i: { sorter: 'fancyNumber' }
                }

                },
                /*Use jQuery to assign zebra stripe CSS, works in IE6+ 
                rather than using pure CSS which doesn't work in IE8 and below.*/

                widgets: ['zebra'],
                widgetZebra: { css: ['normal-row', 'alt-row'] }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

However, Visual Studio doesn't like the `for loop`.  Am I allowed to create a loop inside the `headers` property?  Is there a better alternative for this desired functionality?

EDIT:  I see.  You can't loop inside an object declaration.  I assume the best way to do this would be to create a string and loop through the `numberOfColumns`, appending to the string each time:

```
var headerString = "headers: "

for(var i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++){
    headerString = headerString & i & " { sorter: 'fancyNumber' } ,"
}
```

And then use the substitude the headerString var inside the object declaration?

Is that possible?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the jQuery library. It's a basic JavaScript syntax question, and as you can already see, it's invalid.

Comment: you can't do a for loop inside an object literal declaration.

Comment: Don't build javascript with server side languages. You'd be better off adding a class to the element and selecting it from a separate JS file.

Comment: "i assume the best way..." where are you getting these crazy ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build your object first:

```
var headers = {};
for(var i = 0; i<numberOfColumns; i++) {
    headers[i] = { sorter: 'fancyNumber' };
}

$("#" + gridView).tablesorter({
    headers: headers,
    //...
});
```

I'm guessing at the output you want based on your (incorrect) syntax, so you may need to tweak it a little, but the idea is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't loop inside an object definition, as `for` loops don't evaluate to a value. Neither do `if` statements. Instead, you need to build your object ahead of time:

```
  var headers = {}

  for(var i = 0; i<numberOfColumns; i++)
    headers[i] = { sorter: 'fancyNumber' }

  $("#" + gridView).tablesorter({
    headers: headers

    },
    /*Use jQuery to assign zebra stripe CSS, works in IE6+ 
    rather than using pure CSS which doesn't work in IE8 and below.*/

    widgets: ['zebra'],
    widgetZebra: { css: ['normal-row', 'alt-row'] }
  });
```